# How to set global delimiters in Vue.js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue.js 1.0, I can set global delimiters by the following codes

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
```

But It was removed from Vue.js 2.0.
Must I use the following codes to set delimiters every time?

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to set the delimiters globally, here's the explanation why:

> ...in 2.0 delimiters will become a component-level option, which means you only need to set it for the root instance that relies on in-DOM templates. Any components processed by vueify or vue-loader can just keep using default delimiters.
>
> The change is intended to make it easier to use 3rd party components, since changing the delimiters globally means you will not be able to compile them correctly.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/100

Comment: What a shame. Thank you all the same

Answer (score 8):

For Vue2, try it like this:

```
Vue.options.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
```

Comment: Do I miss something or was that removed? I'm using Vue.js v2.5.13 and this does not work

Comment: @RobinSchambach Check below link. See if it helps.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5697.

And if it doesn't help, could you let me know how are you trying to use it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I accidentally fixed it few seconds ago by creating an example for you. My mistake: `Vue.options.delimiters = ['${', '}'];` was not the first line. I created a Vue object before I set the option.. stupid mistake but I'm used to angular where I can define those options even after defining components

Answer (score 0):

But what about simple workaround. You can prepare class, const or any kind of config like:

**VueConfig.js**

`export const VueConfig = {
    delimiters: ['${', '}']
};`

and then on your **App.js** you simply do

```

```
import {VueConfig} from './VueConfig';

new Vue(
    Object.assign(VueConfig, {
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            msg: 'Oh my app',
        }
    })
);
```

```

Effect is like here: http://take.ms/wiPGR